# Warning that font preload was not used within a few seconds from the window's load event

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I have a website and I've try to speed up loading of fonts so I've put:

```
<link rel="preload" href="{{ '/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}"
      as="font" type="font/woff"/>
<link rel="preload" href="{{ '/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.ttf' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}"
      as="font" type="font/ttf"/>
```

but I've got warning from Chromium:

> The resource http://jcubic.pl/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.ttf was
>   preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from
>   the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for
>   nothing.
>
> The resource http://jcubic.pl/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff was
>   preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from
>   the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for
>   nothing.

I've tried to put the font-face and font-family inside index page in inline style:

```
<style type="text/css">
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'bebas';
     src: url('/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.eot');
     src: url('/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
 }
 header h1 {
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     margin: 20px;
     font-family: bebas;
     font-size: 4em;
 }
</style>
```

but I'm keep getting that warning. How can I remove this warning or why it's showing up? run ajax to fetch the font in window.onload?

Comment: Can you confirm that the h1 is indeed inside the header, that you don't have a font called "Bebas" installed locally and that Chrome is not actually using the eot or svg file?

Comment: By the way, the default font-style for h1 is `bold`, and you have `font-style:normal` specified in the font-face rule. I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: @MrLister It seems that chromium is using svg, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

One point worth going over an [*early loading of fonts*](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/preload-what-is-it-good-for/#early-loading-of-fonts):

> You have to add a **crossorigin** attribute when fetching fonts, as
>   they are fetched using anonymous mode

```
<link rel="preload" href="{{ '/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}"
      as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin/>
<link rel="preload" href="{{ '/css/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.ttf' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}"
      as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin/>
```