# Why does Firefox show font preload warning "The resource at <url> preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds..."?

Tags: html, css, fonts, preload

I've gone over the posts related to this question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456280/the-resource-url-was-preloaded-using-link-preload-but-not-used-within-a-few-se), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406296/preload-fonts-cross-browser-compatibility) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607567/warning-that-font-preload-was-not-used-within-a-few-seconds-from-the-windows-lo)) and tried various things. However, I'm still getting the warnings on Windows 10 in **Firefox** and **Firefox Developer Edition** (but in neither Edge, nor Chrome).

The warnings I get are per font variant, and occur after about 10 seconds:

*The resource at “(url)/test/roboto-light-webfont.woff2” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.*

*The resource at “(url)/test/roboto-regular-webfont.woff2” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.*

*The resource at “(url)/test/roboto-medium-webfont.woff2” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.*

I'm self-hosting the Google font "Robot" on a [**test web page**](https://chris-najman.co.uk/test/).
The folder structure and markup/css are very simple:

```
test/
 index.html
 roboto.css
 roboto-light-webfont.woff
 roboto-light-webfont.woff2
 roboto-regular-webfont.woff2
 roboto-regular-webfont.woff
 roboto-medium-webfont.woff2
 roboto-medium-webfont.woff
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="roboto-light-webfont.woff2"
      as="font"
      type="font/woff2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="roboto-regular-webfont.woff2"
      as="font"
      type="font/woff2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="roboto-medium-webfont.woff2"
      as="font"
      type="font/woff2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Roboto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="roboto.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Roboto (medium: 500)</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Roboto (regular: 400)</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Roboto (light: 300)</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("roboto-light-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("roboto-light-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
/** Regular: 400 **/
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("roboto-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("roboto-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
/** Medium: 500 **/
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url("roboto-medium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("roboto-medium-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Roboto", serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

li {
    font-family: "Roboto", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

p {
    font-family: "Roboto", serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

[Ernesto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366526/ernesto) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406296/preload-fonts-cross-browser-compatibility) suggested that adding `link rel="stylesheet"`,  etc after each preload would eliminate the warning:

```
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="roboto-light-webfont.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="roboto-light-webfont.woff2"
  type="font/woff2"
/>
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="roboto-regular-webfont.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="roboto-regular-webfont.woff2"
  type="font/woff2"
/>
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="roboto-medium-webfont.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="roboto-medium-webfont.woff2"
  type="font/woff2"
/>
```

But I got the same warnings.

Can anyone see any problems with the way I'm preloading the fonts?

Comment: Have you tried adding ```test/``` before the font name href in the CSS? e.g. ```href="test/roboto-light-webfont.woff2"```